# How to change or modify the input text string value before passing it to custom validation in angular reactive forms

Tags: javascript, angular, customvalidator

this is my code for form initialization , i want to convert reading value to number everytime before it passes to validation

```html
this.meterForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'reading': [newReading, this.getValidator(this.meter)],
      'date': [this.date],
      'time': [this.time],
      'comments': [comments]
    });
    
      public getValidator(aMeter: Meter): ValidatorFn {
    if (this.meter.type === this.generalInfo.meterTypes.counter) {
    // I want to change the 'reading' input text field which is a string to number 
      return Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        WorkorderValidators.maxLength(18),
        WorkorderValidators.max(this.meter.maxValue),
        WorkorderValidators.min(this.meter.minValue),
        WorkorderValidators.increment(0.0001, this.meter.minValue),
        WorkorderValidators.precision(3)
      ]);
    } else {
      return Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        this.meterReadingValueValidation(18, 3)
      ]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: For ex? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I have text field which always takes number as input but its in string format so I need to convert and validate the string input for number before performing the number validations everytime

Comment: Is [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp) what you want?

Comment: no , I want to change the incoming input field everytime before sending it to validator functions

Comment: Then add that login inside `getValidator` function?

Comment: Is this question got answered?